# Python and Qt (PyQt) - calling method before resize event

Tags: python, constructor, pyqt

i have a question. There is application class in my program. It is inherited from QtGui.QMainWindow. In **ini** I call my own method which works with graphic. And it should be called before resize event. How can i do that?
Thanks.

EDIT: As you can se [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qevent.html) the value of resize event is 14, and show event is 17. So i should find event with less than 14 value.

I found my problem. In constructor before creating handle of image i'm moving window to some position... So during that action resizeEvent calls. Sorry for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override in your class the `resizeEvent` method (which `QMainWindows` inherits from `QWidget`), see http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qwidget.html#resizeEvent -- in your override, call your other code, then delegate the rest of the work to the parent's version of the method.

Comment: I've already done it. In a few words: in resize event i draw window-background, but object which has handler for the picture is called in __init__. So, when resize event calls, there isn't handler for image, but second calling of that event is ok.

Comment: Alex, it's probably better to link to the latest version of Qt's API. PyQt is currently working with 4.4